# UTF 8 characters don't render in AngularJS 2 template

Tags: angular, utf-8, asp.net-core, angular2-routing

We create angularJS2 application. In some component utf8 character shown normally but some don't. Specially templates that come from router-outlet. For example
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This could be a font or browser setting issue. I'm using utf 8 characters with no problem in my projects. Didn't do any settings to make it work.

Comment: @SefaÜmitOray, I know,, I use it before. but in such stuation we got this issue. There is not anything on web about this problem.

Comment: Without any code, it's hard to help. We have absolutely no idea what the characters are, where they come from, how they are inserted in the page, etc. Check that the template file is properly encoded.

Comment: How can I check it @JBNizet?

Comment: Use your text editor. It should tell you the encoding of the file, and should allow choosing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem also. Open each ts file in notepad, choose save as and choose Enconding: UTF-8.

Comment: İ did it, but after this when I open this files from VS again, they turned back.

Comment: That's weird. Did you check all files?

Comment: Had the same problem, and it worked for me, but i'm not using VS.
But there's most probably a setting in VS that it saves files in UTF-8.